# How to build Adhoc build to test PNS on production mode

Tags: ios5, ios6, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I am working on app which is having PNS. PNS is working good on development mode i have tested it on all devices. Now want to test with production mode i have created all certificate on production mode. but now i dont know what is the next procedure. How to create Adhoc build so that it will work on production mode also on stack overflow i read that we need to remove device token which we are using for dev mode so that token will will not same? Is it right way and also let me know how we can create adhoc build for PNS prodcution to work?

Comment: Please post your answer as new answer to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea: you need to build an AdHoc build of your app. First, you have to go to the Apple Provisioning portal and build an AdHoc provisioning profile for your app. The steps are similar to what you did to build the developer one.

This is very similar to the distribution build of your app. Compile your app in release mode (or AdHoc mode if Xcode has set that up for you). At this point, you can check your build settings so that no certificate is associated with the AdHoc build you are doing. Later on, you will select the AdHoc provisioning profile.

When the build is done, Organizer will open and you will see your app in the list. Select the build from the list and then click on **Distribute**. Select the second option "**Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment**". In the next screen, pick the AdHoc provisioning profile you generated previously. Hit **Export**.

At this point, a .IPA file will be generated that you can then install on your device by either uploading to a server and downloading by navigating to its URL OR, the easier option, is to drag/drop your IPA file to iTunes and sync your app from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
this links are help to you visit 

http://kb.applingua.com/2011/10/testing-an-app-on-your-own-device-ios/
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2009/01/uuid-hint.html
http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/


push notification form client server ->it receives Apns and send to the ->appropriate mobile
note:client sever-> must be send notification with token
```

Comment: its OK but how we can test for PNS in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

[William Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291240/william-hu) proposition to this question (was putted in wrong place):

> **@William Hu**
>
> > The answer:
> >
> > 1) Build AdHoc build for the app. Just got to Apple Provisioning portal and build an AdHoc provisioning profile for the app.
> >
> > 2) Check the "Building Settings", "Code Signing", choose the profile you just generate (or AdHoc mode if Xcode has set that up for you)
> >
> > 3) Choose "Product" -> "Archive", then "Organizer" window will open automatic. Press "Distribute" button. Select the second option "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment".
> >     Then save the ".IPA" file to your disk.
> >
> > 4) Drag this file (along with profile) into iTunes to test. Also check http://testflightapp.com make test very easy and simple to use.